# Adding field to ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to add one more field to my view. So basically, after displaying a town in the dropdown menu, I want to display the `(*ABR)` field as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVWTs.jpg).

As you can see from the picture, after `Advance Ortopedical`, I just want to add a filed called `*ABR`.

```
<table class="table datatable-responsive datatable-medical-map" id="medProviders" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-info">
            <th>Medical Provider (* Choose one)</th>
            <th>Distance (miles)</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{
            int i = 0;

            foreach (var item in medProviders)
            {
                <tr class="sortList" style="cursor:pointer" id="increment-@i" data-id="@item.Id" data-lat="@item.Latitude" data-long="@item.Longitude">
                    <td>@item.Firstname</td>
                    <td id="distance-@i"></td>
                    <td id="duration-@i"></td>
                </tr>
                i++;
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<p id="medicalValidation"></p>
```

Any suggestions or comments on how to do this in a simple way?

Comment: what do you mean by adding ABR? Do you want to abbreviate the name Advance Ortopedical? If that's what you want how do you want to abbreviate. i mean what format? first 3 letters?

Comment: Just belove Advance Ortopedical add *ABR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code. This will add 1 more field at the end of table.

```
    @{
        int i = 0;

        foreach (var item in medProviders)
        {
            <tr class="sortList" style="cursor:pointer" id="increment-@i" data-id="@item.Id" data-lat="@item.Latitude" data-long="@item.Longitude">
                <td>
                   @item.Firstname
                   <br>*ABR</br>
                </td>
                <td id="distance-@i"></td>
                <td id="duration-@i"></td>
            </tr>
            i++;
        }


    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: But maybe you didnt understand me, I just want to add belove the text tag *ABR, as you can see from picture
https://imgur.com/ge5tTyS